# Erro ao compilar no DEV-C++(SDL)

Tags: c++, dev-c++, sdl

Eu fiz todo o procedimento para usar o SDL2, porem quando vou compilar acontece o seguinte erro

```
[Error]SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

Esse é o conteúdo da linha onde acontece o erro

```
<SDL/SDL.h>
```

Oque devo fazer ?? pesquisei muito e não achei nada que resolvesse meu problema.

Instalei da [forma manual](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/devcpp/index.php)

E pelo [DevPak](http://jomarumu.blogspot.com.br/2010/01/tutorial-sdl-da-instalacao-ate.html)([DOWNLOAD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/devpaks/files/SDL/SDL%201.2.8/SDL-1.2.8-2spec.DevPak/download?use_mirror=ufpr))

Comment: Você tem o [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) instalado?

Comment: Editei minha pergunta para entender melhor.

Comment: Você especificou o diretório do SDL conforme explicado no tutorial? *Dev C++* ⇢ *Compiler Options* ⇢ aba `Directories`⇢ aba `C++ includes`, veja  a [imagem](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/devcpp/added.png).

Comment: O problema da compilação se resolveu, porem agora acontece esse problema i.stack.imgur.com/NtBA0.png no arquivo Makefile.win

Comment: Não é um erro, é apenas uma mensagem avisando que o arquivo foi modificado, e por isso, é necessário recarregá-lo novamente.

Comment: Sim, mas esse aviso não permite rodar o programa.

Comment: O que acontece se você confirmar a mensagem e compilar novamente o código?

Comment: A mensagem aparece novamente.

Comment: Clique na aba "Compile Log" e poste o que apareceu lá.

Comment: Apareceu o seguinte: http://pastebin.com/Gk70w0CZ

Comment: Lucas, apesar da ajuda do colega @qmechanik, a sua pergunta já mudou de erro duas vezes (incialmente era um problema com a falta da configuração do diretório de includes, agora é um problema com a falta de configuração do diretório de libs - você seguiu atentamente o tutorial que menciona?). O fato é que o SOPT *não é um fórum*, e intenciona ter perguntas objetivas passíveis de serem respondidas de forma igualmente objetiva (para serem úteis também para outras pessoas *além de você*). Se ao longo do seu trabalho/aprendizado/lazer você tiver outras dúvidas, poste em perguntas diferentes.

Comment: Eu também sugiro que você faça o [tour], se ainda não o fez.

Comment: Vou abrir uma nova pergunta

Comment: Não sei porque é que o Makefile está a ser alterado, mas no log aparecem ainda erros do linker: para além de indicar os caminhos (paths) para os cabeçalhos do SDL, também é preciso indicar as bibliotecas (libraries). Será que falta isso? http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/devcpp/lib.png

Comment: Sim, eu fiz tudo exatamente como o tutorial, porem continua dando o mesmo erro no Makefile.win